# Сессия в Node.js быстро сбрасывается

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, сессия, backend

Сессия устанавливается после авторизации. Если попереключаться по ссылкам внутри сайта, все работает нормально. Стоит оставить вкладку неактивной, через 5-10 минут сессия сбрасывается.
Код конфигурации сессии:

```
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'you secret key',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
}));
```

С параметрами saveUninitialized и resave по-разному игрался, пробовал в разных комбинациях ставить true/false. Не помогло. За время жизни сессии должно отвечать свойство maxAge, я его поставил в 1 месяц, но она все равно живет 5-10 минут.

Возможно мне сейчас будут советовать в качестве хранилища сессии - Redis, но я хочу узнать как исправить ошибку именно в данной конфигурации, без использования хранилищ вроде Redis и MongoDB.

Поскажите еще как генерировать ключ для поля secret.

Comment: Для начала определитесь что именно сбрасывается. Теряется кука? Теряется сессия на сервере? Может сервер перезапустился?